# Using PostgreSQL COPY FROM STDIN

Tags: postgresql, go

Is it possible to use PostgreSQL's `COPY FROM STDIN` statement to load data from CSV file by passing some sort of `Reader` or `Writer` object the same way it's done in Java? What library should I use? Kotlin example for reference:

```
val cm = CopyManager(conn as BaseConnection)
val total = cm.copyIn("COPY my_table FROM STDIN FORMAT csv", inputStream)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the two most popular Golang postgres libraries:

#### lib/pq

The driver supports this via the standard library methods, but you'll need to consume the `io.Reader` variable to pass each CSV row through.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"

    "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), os.Interrupt)
    defer cancel()

    if err := run(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func run(ctx context.Context) error {
    // Open CSV file (this could also be os.Stdin, etc)
    f, err := os.Open("/tmp/csv")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    // Open database connection using pq driver
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Execute copy
    if err = copyFrom(ctx, db, "my_table", f); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func copyFrom(ctx context.Context, db *sql.DB, table string, r io.Reader) error {
    query := fmt.Sprintf("COPY %s FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT csv)", pq.QuoteIdentifier(table))

    tx, err := db.BeginTx(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer tx.Rollback()

    stmt, err := tx.PrepareContext(ctx, query)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    sc := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for sc.Scan() {
        if _, err = stmt.ExecContext(ctx, sc.Text()); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    if err = sc.Err(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if _, err = stmt.ExecContext(ctx); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return tx.Commit()
}
```

**Note**

1. lib/pq is in [maintenance mode](https://github.com/lib/pq#status)
2. Numerous data races have been reported in the underlying code that handles `COPY` statements, with at least [one still open](https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/853)

#### jackc/pgx

The lower level `pgconn.PgConn` type has a `CopyFrom` method that allows you to pass an arbitrary statement and `io.Reader`. If you're connecting via the stdlib `db` package, you can still get access to the underlying `pgconn.PgConn` as shown below, although there are other ways of handling connections / pools, etc, when using pgx, so it's worth taking a look at those too.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/stdlib"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), os.Interrupt)
    defer cancel()

    if err := run(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func run(ctx context.Context) error {
    // Open CSV file (this could also be os.Stdin, etc)
    f, err := os.Open("/tmp/csv")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    // Open database connection using pgx driver
    db, err := sql.Open("pgx", "postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Execute copy
    if err = copyFrom(ctx, db, "my_table", f); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func copyFrom(ctx context.Context, db *sql.DB, table string, r io.Reader) error {
    query := fmt.Sprintf("COPY %s FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT csv)", pgx.Identifier{table}.Sanitize())

    conn, err := db.Conn(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    return conn.Raw(func(driverConn any) error {
        pgConn := driverConn.(*stdlib.Conn).Conn().PgConn()
        _, err := pgConn.CopyFrom(ctx, r, query)
        return err
    })
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `stdlib.Conn` does not have a `Conn()`. Is here any workaround? Now I just create additional connection using pgconn for bulk upload

Comment: @VladimirDergachev - it does have a `Conn()` function - you can see it here https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/5c63f646f820ca9696fc3515c1caf2a557d562e5/stdlib/sql.go#L413-L416